# Best way to build a string in multiple pieces?

Tags: c++, gcc, c-preprocessor

I'm building a large C++ program with a variety of different compile-time options, selected by `#define`s (or the `-D` option).

I want to have a version string that lists a number of them as tags, and ideally, to have that version string defined as a literal, not a constant.

Currently, I'm looking at three options, none of which is ideal.

1. Piles of preprocessor defines

   ```
   #ifdef AAA
   #define AAAMSG " [A]"
   #else
   #define AAAMSG ""
   #endif
   #ifdef BBB
   #define BBBMSG " [B]"
   #else
   #define BBBMSG ""
   #endif
   // ...
   #define REVISION __DATE__ " " __TIME__ AAAMSG BBBMSG CCCMSG DDDMSG
   ```
2. Build a constant

   ```
   const char *const REVISION=__DATE__ " " __TIME__
   #ifdef AAA
   " [A]"
   #endif
   #ifdef BBB
   " [B]"
   #endif
   // ...
   ;
   ```
3. Redefine the token

   ```
   #define REVISION __DATE__ " " __TIME__
   #ifdef AAA
   #define REVISION REVISION " [A]"
   #endif
   #ifdef BBB
   #define REVISION REVISION " [B]"
   #endif
   // ...
   ```

The first one is incredibly verbose (imagine that with half a dozen independent elements) and error-prone. The second one is far better, but it creates a constant instead of a literal, so I can't use it as part of another string - example:

```
send(sock,"rev " REVISION "\n",sizeof(REVISION)+4,0);
```

It seems silly to use run-time string manipulation (an sprintf or somesuch) for a compile-time constant. The third example, of course, just straight-up doesn't work, but it is pretty much what I'm trying to do.

Is there some alternative method?

Comment: Should it not be `sizeof(REVISION)+5`?

Comment: You may be interested in [constexp](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_thread/thread/d9bddd4105f1441e?hl=en&pli=1) compile time string processing

Comment: @JoeMcGrath - no, because the sizeof includes the \0 at the end, which I don't transmit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing off this question with the comment that I'm sticking with option 1. There appears to be no way to do what I was hoping to do, so the imperfect remains. Thanks to those who contributed!

Answer (score 0):

```
#define AAAMSG ""
#define BBBMSG ""

#ifdef AAA
    #define AAAMSG " [A]"
#endif
```

define all your empties.. then treat it like a switch. 
If you keep the types the same, you shouldn't have any issues with redefining..

Note: I am not 100% sure this works, but changing a define can be done.

Comment: Changing a define requires undeffing it first (gcc specially permits you to redefine something as what it already is, but this is a substantive change), so this isn't any less clunky. I did consider the possibility, but it's not materially different from my original option 1, and it separates pieces of one option's code.